# UITextField seems to ignore clipsToBounds property

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitextfield, ios-simulator

I am creating a custom search bar by subclassing the `UITextField`. For some reason, the search bar has a *very subtle, weird white line/border* around the edges. The issue only exists on my iPhone 13 Pro Max - on the simulator everything works perfectly fine.

> notice the slight white border around the pill shaped search text field. Almost like it has a white background color.

[image]

I tried to battle this by setting `layer.masksToBounds` and `clipsToBounds` to true, but unfortunately that doesn't work either.

**This is my code:**

```swift
public class MyCustomSearchBar: UITextField {
    public override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        self.backgroundColor = Theme.GRAY800
        self.borderStyle = .roundedRect
        
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.clipsToBounds = true
        
        self.autocorrectionType = .no
        
        self.textColor = .white
        self.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Search", attributes: [.foregroundColor : Theme.GRAY400, .font: FontFamily.ProximaNova.regular.font(size: 16)])
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

If I add a border width and color, everything looks normal again:

[image]

**Question:**

Why is this a problem on my iPhone but not in the simulator? Why do I manually have to set the border width and color to avoid those white "fragments"?

Comment: Is it antialiasing caused by the resolution of the device screen? What if you add layer border color / width, does that help?

Comment: @matt thanks for your comment. I just updated my original post (please have a look at the picture). If I add a border, everything looks normal. Why is that? And how can I battle that?

Comment: It's likely the `.borderStyle = .roundedRect` ... adding a border. Use `.none` and adjust the `textRect` and `editingRect`, and add/remove your own border as needed.

Answer (score 0):

create border and corner manually, this is an example:

```
let myTextField = MyCustomSearchBar()
```

in viewDidLoad set constraints

```
view.addSubview(myTextField)
    myTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    myTextField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.width - 40).isActive = true
    myTextField.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    myTextField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

now assign border width, border color e round corner in MyCustomSearchBar class

```
public class MyCustomSearchBar: UITextField {
public override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    
    self.backgroundColor = .yourColor
    self.borderStyle = .none
    
    self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 16
    self.clipsToBounds = true
    
    self.layer.borderWidth = 2
    self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    
    self.autocorrectionType = .no
    
    self.textColor = .white
    self.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Search", attributes: [.foregroundColor : UIColor.lightGray, .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .regular)])
    self.addPadding(padding: .left(20)) // this is a extra
    self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
 }
}
```

to add padding spacing to your textField use my extension:

```
extension UITextField {

enum PaddingSpace {
    case left(CGFloat)
    case right(CGFloat)
    case equalSpacing(CGFloat)
}

func addPadding(padding: PaddingSpace) {
    
    self.leftViewMode = .always
    self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    
    switch padding {
        
    case .left(let spacing):
        let leftPaddingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: spacing, height: self.frame.height))
        self.leftView = leftPaddingView
        self.leftViewMode = .always
        
    case .right(let spacing):
        let rightPaddingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: spacing, height: self.frame.height))
        self.rightView = rightPaddingView
        self.rightViewMode = .always
        
    case .equalSpacing(let spacing):
        let equalPaddingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: spacing, height: self.frame.height))
        // left
        self.leftView = equalPaddingView
        self.leftViewMode = .always
        // right
        self.rightView = equalPaddingView
        self.rightViewMode = .always
    }
  }
}
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: why do I have to set the border width & color manually? What causes the behavior I've been experiencing?

Comment: @linus_hologram i read your update after posting ... I don't know why ....